# SigPlus.Net Connected Tablet

Tags: c#, .net, hardware, topaz-signatures

I am developing an interface to a Topaz signature pad using the [SigPlus.Net](http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/sigplusnet/sigplusnet.htm) library.

I’ve used the `sigPlus.GetTabletComTest()` method to see if the signature pad is connected via USB (found [here](http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/sigplusnet/Topaz.SigPlusNET.GetTabletComTest.html)). The method always returns 0, regardless if the pad is connected by USB or not.

I found another section on the Topaz website that appears to be for VB6 but is something like I’d want to do [here](http://www.topazsystems.com/faq/softwarefaq.htm#11). It says there is a method called `TabletConnectQuery()` that indicates if the tablet is connected. This method does not appear to be valid in SigPlus.Net.

How does one determine whether or not the device is connected to the computer via USB?

Here is the basic code, the sigPlus object is instantiated in InitializeComponent:

```
public frmSignatureCapture()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (sigPlus.GetTabletComTest() == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Topaz Signature Device Connected", "Error");
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topaz tech support confirmed that the `TabletConnectQuery()` is available on the SigPlus object. The documentation [here](http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/sigplusnet/Topaz.SigPlusNET.GetTabletComTest.html) does not reflect this method though.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks for posting.